# Compare AIC and BIC results in R

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, multiple-regression, aic

The data I am using can be found [here](http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_Data_BMI_Regression). These data were originally taken to explore multiple regression to predict the percentage of body fat based on 13 predictors (body measurements) that are easily measured.

We take the response variable as $y = \frac{1}{D}$; $D$ is a measured body density.

When I was trying to compare the $AIC$ and $BIC$ result, I got results as:

```
> BIC(lm(inverseD ~ Abdomen2Circumf + Weight.lb. + WristCircumf + ForearmCircumf, data = datanew)) 
[1] -1629.494
> AIC(lm(inverseD ~ Abdomen2Circumf + Weight.lb. + WristCircumf + ForearmCircumf, data = datanew))
[1] -1650.671
```

In this example the number of parameters $K=4$ and the sample size $n=252$. 
The formula for $AIC$ and $BIC$ are
$$AIC=-2\log L +2K$$
$$BIC=-2\log L +K\log n$$
where $L$ denotes the likelihood function.

I thought the difference between $AIC$ and $BIC$ should be
$$k[\log n-2]=4(\log 252 -2)=14.12$$
But the numerical result shows not.

Any help with that? Many thanks!

Comment: The formulas for AIC and BIC can vary up to a constant that depends on the data but not the model; the formulas you write above aren't "the" formulas.  Rather than focus on the difference between AIC and BIC (which is not useful anyway), check whether you can replicate either AIC or BIC.

Comment: @TheLaconic Thanks for replying. By saying "replicate", do you mean that write my own source code to compute AIC or BIC?

Comment: I just mean do the calculation yourself.  If you want to call that "write your own source code", that's technically true, I guess, but it's kind of a fancy way to describe it, and it's not much beyond what you're already doing in R.  You just need to get $log L$, which shouldn't be that difficult, although I can't remember how to do it offhand...

Comment: Could you explain how you know the number of parameters is $K=4$ and not $K=6$ as indicated by the difference between AIC and BIC?  Remember, there are additional parameters not explicit in the formula: namely, the constant and the error variance.  There can be even more (depending on how you have processed the data, because categorical variables require multiple parameters), but that's not needed for a full explanation of your results.  As a check, store the result of `lm` and pass it to `logLik`: what does it report for "df"?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for replying! The `df=6`, so I guess I will have to include the intercept and the error variance in the parameters for the linear regression cases?

Comment: @whuber Sorry for more questions, so since I was doing the multivariable regression, so the variance for the error should be a matrix, there will be more than one unknowns in that matrix, then why that counts as 1 more parameter here?

Comment: There is only one parameter for the variance because your software assumes the errors are independent with a single common variance.  Note this has nothing whatsoever to do with the number of explanatory variables you are employing in this multiple regression.